# Поиск с динамической переменной - PHP

Tags: php

Есть стандартная конструкция:

```
$temperature_find="<div class=\"report_text temperature\" style=\"color:#A1B2C3;\">";
// далее.
$str_pos = strripos($site_contents, $temperature_find);
```

Нашли позицию выражения в тексте. Хорошо.
Но вот встал в ступор, так как параметр `color:#A1B2C3` динамичный. Он постоянно меняется.

Как используя регулярные выражения, модернизировать данную конструкцию?

---

**UPD** - Не стал себе тренировать мозг, сделал так:

```
$temperature_find="<div class=\"report_text temperature\"";
$str_pos = strripos($site_contents, $temperature_find);
$code_for_out = substr($site_contents, $str_pos+60, 2);
```

*Чувствую, что код из разряда 1+1+1+1=4, хотя правильнее бы было 2²=4*

Comment: а чего вы с ним сделать то хотите по итогу?

Comment: @teran, Далее так:
`$str_pos_end = strripos($site_contents, $temperature_find_end);
$code_out_data = substr($site_contents, $str_pos, ($str_pos_end-$str_pos));`

Comment: а на русском можно? :) вам получить значение `color` надо просто, или заменить его, или что?

Comment: в теле юлока <div>, который я ищу, и который имеет цвет, храниться информация. Вот её я и хочу вытащить. Не цвет div, а то, что обрамляет div.

http://krasnovosti.ru/soft/temperatura/temperatura_v2_for_application.php

Comment: ну дак и приведите ваш html код целиком, и укажите, что оттуда вы хотите вытащить.

Comment: @teran: https://www.worldweatheronline.com/krasnoyarsk-weather/krasnoyarsk/ru.aspx?day=0

Comment: вооружитесь инструментами, работающими с HTML DOM. поиск подстрок и регулярки для данной задачи особо не нужны. simple html dom и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали про `preg_match`.
Реализация:

```
preg_match("/<div class=\"report_text temperature\" style=\"color:(#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6});\">/", $site_contents, $matches);
$str_pos = strripos($site_contents, $matches[0]);
$code_for_out = substr($site_contents, $str_pos+60, 2);
```